# Updating the XML file using PHP script

Tags: php, xml

I'm making an interface-website to update a concert-list on a band-website.
The list is stored as an XML file an has this structure :

I already wrote a script that enables me to add a new gig to the list, this was relatively easy...
Now I want to write a script that enables me to edit a certain gig in the list.
Every Gig is Unique because of the first attribute : "id" .
I want to use this reference to edit the other attributes in that Node.

My PHP is very poor, so I hope someone could put me on the good foot here...

My PHP script :

Answer (score 2):

Well i dunno what your XML structure looks like but:

```
<gig id="someid">
 <venue></venue>
 <day></day>
 <month></month>
<year></year>
</gig>

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement('gig.xml',null, true);
$gig = $xml->xpath('//gig[@id="'.$_POST['id'].'"]');
$gig->venue = $_POST['venue'];
$gig->month = $_POST['month'];
// etc..

$xml->asXml('gig.xml)'; // save back to file
```

now if instead all these data points are attributes you can use `$gig->attributes()->venue` to access it.

There is no need for the loop really unless you are doing multiple updates with one post - you can get at any specific record via an XPAth query. SimpleXML is also a lot lighter and a lot easier to use for this type of thing than DOMDOcument - especially as you arent using the feature of DOMDocument.

Comment: +1 for SimpleXML.. Checkout these resources to have a better understanding of what's been done here..
PHP's SimpleXML class - http://devzone.zend.com/article/688
and Xpath - http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to load the xml file in a [domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with

```
<?
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load("xmlfile.xml");
//find the tags that you want to update
$tags = $xml->getElementsByTagName("GIG");
//find the tag with the id you want to update
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   if($tag->getAttribute("id") == $id) { //found the tag, now update the attribute
      $tag->setAttribute("[attributeName]", "[attributeValue]");
   }
}

//save the xml
$xml->save();
?>
```

code is untested, but it's a general idea

Comment: thanks for your response...
$tag->setAttribute("[attributeName]", "[attributeValue]"); this code alone is not working...please suggest it...

Comment: how are you trying to use it? have a look at the documentation first to make sure you're using it correctly http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

Comment: @viswanathan : the problem you are facing is because of the save() method . You need to pass a parameter to this method with the name of the XML file that you need to update .